# Using R on a linux computing cluster

Tags: r

I would like to run R packages on our university cluster (Linux). Looks like there are several Linux binaries: debian, redhat, suse, and ubuntu.

1) Which binary is most appropriate for submitting jobs on a cluster?

2) Once copied to a folder on the cluster, does the program need to be compiled?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to ask this on Super Super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to compile `R` from source, it should be available in any major Linux distribution's repository for easy download and installation. For example, `sudo apt-get install r-base` will install R for Ubuntu. This [guide](http://www.r-bloggers.com/instructions-for-installing-using-r-on-amazon-ec2/) to setting up an R-studio server may be helpful, though it is geared to Amazon EC2 use. If you need particular R packages installed you can write an R script to install them within R.